# Nomenclature of a branched alkane

Tags: nomenclature

[image]

Here I need to give the systematic name of this molecule so I decided to first find the longuest chain of carbons which seems to be the one I put in red. Then I have 2 ethyls at 3 and 4 and I have an isobutyl at 6 so would the name be

3,4-diethyl-6-isobutyldecane ?

Answer (score 4):

The name ‘3,4-diethyl-6-isobutyldecane’ that is proposed in the question is unambiguous and describes the correct structure. However, it corresponds to obsolete IUPAC recommendations.

The retained prefix ‘isobutyl’ was still contained in the [1993 recommendations](http://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/93/r93_682.htm) but is explicitly no longer recommended in the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001).*

According to current IUPAC recommendations, the preferred prefix for the group $\ce{(CH3)2CH-CH2-{}}$ is ‘2-methylpropyl’.

Therefore, the preferred IUPAC name (PIN) for the compound given in the question is 3,4-diethyl-6-(2-methylpropyl)decane.

[image: 3,4-diethyl-6-(2-methylpropyl)decane]

Answer (score 0):

Isobuytl is a trivial name (Although it is very clear what is means, even if not formally correct).

Try:

3,4-diethyl-6-(2-methylpropyl)-decane